# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'

Tags: typescript, axios, nestjs

I am a nest.js beginner and I am trying to implement Axios with my code and this error occurs and I would like to fix it.

```
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'Socket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle +188941ms
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'Socket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (D:\CUSportcomplex-register\sso-reg\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\CUSportcomplex-register\sso-reg\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at ExpressAdapter.reply (D:\CUSportcomplex-register\sso-reg\node_modules\@nestjs\platform-express\adapters\express-adapter.js:24:57)
    at RouterResponseController.apply (D:\CUSportcomplex-register\sso-reg\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-response-controller.js:13:36)
    at D:\CUSportcomplex-register\sso-reg\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:173:48
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async D:\CUSportcomplex-register\sso-reg\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:47:13
    at async D:\CUSportcomplex-register\sso-reg\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

This is my app.service.ts

```
async validateSSO(appticket): Promise<SsoContent> {
        let instance = axios.create({
            baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/",
            headers: {
                'DeeAppId': config.DeeAppId,
                'DeeAppSecret': config.DeeAppSecret,
                'DeeTicket': appticket
            }
        });
        instance.get("/serviceValidation")
            .then(response => {
                this.ssoContent = response;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return (error);
            });

        return this.ssoContent;

    }
```

and this is my app.controller.ts

```
    @Get('validation/:appticket')
    async validateSSO(
        @Param('appticket') appticket: string
        //DeeAppTicket is sented via Front-end
    ): Promise<SsoContent> {
        return this.registeringService.validateSSO(appticket);
    }
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I faced the same siily mistake.. you probably want to do this
`this.ssoContent = response.data`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First of all nest.js provides you HttpService out of the box that you may inject it through DI:
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module

Second - you are trying to store whole response object which is complex data structure and contains circular dependencies as it stated in error message (TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON)

What you should do is either you map the data you need instead of storing whole circular object,

or you should look up to some libs that could parse circular json: https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatted

Comment: No problem. If you will struggle more. Let us know, and we will try to help you! :)

Comment: alr use flatted package but still not solve

Answer (score 26):

Today I had this problem and one way I managed to solve it was instead of return:

```js
this.ssoContent = response;
```

I returned:

```js
this.ssoContent = response.data;
```

Comment: You need to improve this answer it helps others. just returning data actually works

Answer (score 16):

Rather than storing the whole response object which is a circular object. You can store the `data` object key of the response. That should work just fine

Answer (score 11):

This also happens when you forget to put the keyword *await* in your *async* function.

Comment: Thanks man simple but notable

Comment: Async await has nothing to do with the circular dependency. It is more of a mechanism to return promises. Whereas circular dependency is caused by returning the entire response object inside an HTTP response again. Hence we just extract the data object from the response and return it, to avoid the circular dependency.

Answer (score 5):

'This also happens when you forget to put the keyword await in your async function.'

solved for me.

how silly I feel....

Comment: This is really just a "Thanks" for [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69603485/10871073) and should be deleted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Async await has nothing to do with the circular dependency. It is more of a mechanism to return promises. Whereas circular dependency is caused by returning the entire response object inside an HTTP response again. Hence we just extract the data object from the response and return it, to avoid the circular dependency.

Answer (score 5):

#2023

short answer:

```
const response = await axios(url, body, options );
return response.data;
```

Long answer:

Do you remember the http request object ?
when you make axios call , store the response and return the same.
you basically return the whole http object which causes circular dependency.
hence you extract only data object from it and return.

Answer (score 1):

I have that's problem when my app(nest.js app) try to send request to another apps(Nest.js apps). The problem is response of server. I can not resolve it, instead use superagent library. https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent
It is resolved easily.

Answer (score 1):

I am using TypeORM with NestJS and got several times the following error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'EntityMetadata'
|     property 'ownColumns' -> object with constructor 'Array'
|     index 0 -> object with constructor 'ColumnMetadata'
--- property 'entityMetadata' closes the circle
```

It was because I forgot the `getOne()` or `getMany()` at the end of my query builder.

Answer (score 1):

### Fix for me is to not stringify axios response object.

**wrong**

```
const payload = { name: "M Hmzara Rajput" }
console.log("request:", JSON.stringify(payload));
const response = await axios.post(`http://server:port/endpoint`, payload);
// Don't JSON.stringify to an http object instead response.data
console.log("response:", JSON.stringify(response));
```

**right**

```
const payload = { name: "M Hmzara Rajput" }
console.log("request:", JSON.stringify(payload));
const response = await axios.post(`http://server:port/endpoint`, payload);
console.log("response:", JSON.stringify(response.data));
```

Answer (score 1):

### Wrong usage: All this objects I'm try to return are complex objects with a circular stuff.

```
@Post()
async someRequestName() {
  return this.httpService.post( // this is Observable<AxiosResponse>
    'http://localhost:3001/api/some-endpoint',
  );
}
```

```
@Post()
async someRequestName() {
  return firstValueFrom( // this is Promise<Observable<AxiosResponse>>
    this.httpService.post(
      'http://localhost:3001/api/some-endpoint',
    ),
  );
}
```

```
@Post()
async someRequestName() {
  const data = await firstValueFrom(
    this.httpService.post(
      'http://localhost:3001/api/some-endpoint',
    ),
  );
  return data; // this is as well Promise<Observable<AxiosResponse>>
}
```

### Correct usage: `data.data` includes only returned value from request. No circular stuff inside.

```
@Post()
async someRequestName() {
  const data = await firstValueFrom(
    this.httpService.post(
      'http://localhost:3001/api/some-endpoint',
    ),
  );
  return data.data; // this is JSON response
}
```

### Summarize

Methods with decorators as @Post(), @Get() and etc, should return simple object (JSON), not complex object with methods and circular refs. You can't pass methods and circular refs over http protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had this problem and invest lots of time. It is working for me.

from
this.ssoContent = response;

To
this.ssoContent = response.data;

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 3rd-party helper for this: `circular json`. ref:https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-json

Install it with: `npm i circular-json` OR `npm i circular-json --force`

code:

```
const CircularJSON = require('circular-json');
const obj=CircularJSON.stringify(object)
```

here object can be circular or normal json object.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to this issue, but if by any chance you came to this tread with this issue happened in React, it might also be because of using ? on an unknown type:

```
type Test = unknown
const test:Test
{test ? <div>test</div> : null}
```

This will throw this error, you can change it to:

```
{Boolean(test) ? <div>test</div> : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this error just because I am wrapping object in to an object. bolded line cause error in my case

```
 for (const record of records) {
     const { createdAt } = record;
     const dateOnly = createdAt.toISOString().split('T')[0]
     if (!organizedData[`${dateOnly}`]) {
         organizedData[`${dateOnly}`] = [];
         }
     const joinedData = { ...record }; <<< This is causing error for me>>>
     organizedData[`${dateOnly}`].push(joinedData);
}
```