# POST request to GraphQL returns 400

Tags: javascript, axios, graphql

This is my code:

```js
const result = await axios({
      url: "https://exampleurl.com",
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data: {
        query: `query {
                  footer {
                    title
                }
              }`,
      },
    })
```

There are no variables required for this call.

So this gives me 400 which makes me think there is something wrong with my body payload? But I can't see anything wrong with it. Maybe I am blind.

I have also tried stringifying the data object like this:

```js
JSON.stringify({
        query: `query {
                  footer {
                    title
                }
              }`,
      }),
```

But then I get this error:

```
"stack": "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON\n    -->
starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'\n    |     property
'socket' -> object with constructor 'Socket'\n    --- property
'_httpMessage' closes the circle\n    at JSON.stringify
```

I have checked out other similar posts but can't seem to fix this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64735881/typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json-starting-at-object-with-con)

Comment: The issue is not the client code but instead on the server side, check the duplicate post I shared.

Comment: But that circular error I only get when I stringify my graphql query which I don't think I need to do based on other example posts.

Comment: does this query work/was tested in the playground?

Comment: Yeah and it works in graphiql, I also tried it in postman to hit my local server and it also works

Comment: exactly the same query? then compare axios network request (body+headers) with working one

Comment: yep I did and I made sure they were same too

Comment: compare carefully ALL request details ... equal requests => both working requests

Comment: Just resolved the issue, it was not really related to my request at all. Will post the answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, I was trying to log out `result` and because axios is such a big object, it was clashing with one of my custom logger. I logged result.data and I finally got 200 response.